# error in making android application with RAD Studio (Delphi)

Tags: android, delphi

I started "Create a new Multi-Device Application (Delphi)" project.
Of course, the phone was inserted into the right usb port, but I found this situation.

[image: Click to see the photo.]

You can advise me to click "Refresh", but I've done it enough.

I compiled an empty app with simple settings and found an error.

(please look at red colored part.)

[image: Click to see the photo.]

You can advise me to install smartphone driver, but the computer can recognize my phone already.

This is my device manager (It's not english. but you can see that It's recognized.)

(please look at blue colored part. I can't upload more than 2 pictures.)

I use Samsung Galaxy S5. what did I miss?
is there an absolute smartphone driver?
or.. Did I miss some very important settings?

If you think there's not enough information, tell me what you need.

Comment: It doesn't matter that the computer can recognize your phone already. You need the proper USB driver for ADB and the other NDK tools. The documentation has clear, easy to follow steps for configuring your device. You should follow them. It also has step-by-step troubleshooting information in case you run into difficulties.

Comment: @Ken, can you post the (version-agnostic) links, just for completeness?

Comment: @blong: I don't have a version agnostic link available, but the current documentation can be found starting with http://docwiki.embarcadero.com/RADStudio/Berlin/en/Configuring_Your_System_to_Detect_Your_Android_Device which covers the basics and has a list of *See Also * items at the bottom which lead to more information about various steps.

Comment: Ok, so the version-independent link is http://docwiki.embarcadero.com/RADStudio/en/Configuring_Your_System_to_Detect_Your_Android_Device

Comment: thank you for answers! I solved it. it was because of developer mode.